# How to execute different sass files based on a css class?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am wondering how can I can include a different sass file (theme) based on a certain class?

Now we got 3 apps which all have an unique css class for its styling (.app1 {.background-color: red;})

Now i want to include sass framework and seperate all the css/sass per app label. In order to achieve this we define a base.scss. In this scss we want to reach this:

if .app1 then execute app1.scss
else if .app2 then execute app2.scss
else if .app3 then executr app3.scss
else empty

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Not sure if this will answer your question so I'll put this as a comment. I'm not sure how your app has been architected but the only way that I can think of that you can conditionally load items is to use something like Webpack, which would enable you to load certain features for certain files.

Comment: Since Sass is precompiled, it won't be possible to dynamically choose which CSS it will output based on the HTML that the browser is seeing. Or, another way to say it: by the time you're looking at which `.app` class is on your page, Sass will have been compiled to CSS & linked on your page a long time ago.

If your goal is to limit file size by including only what's necessary, a JavaScript solution could look at your HTML contents & dynamically include CSS. But if you're not concerned with file size, you can actually import Sass files *within* a Sass class (like `.app`).

Comment: You can use if statements in SASS to choose between themes. This might help you get started. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaVxSc11t3Y

Answer (score 0):

Use a namespace and apply it as a class to the root element. Wrap SASS statements in the appropriate namespaces. You can separate them into different files (partials) and combine them when they get compiled.

```
// in file _app1.scss
.app1 {
    // rules you want applied in the "app1" case
}

// in file _app2.scss
.app2 {
    // rules you want applied in the "app2" case
}

...
```

If you separate files into `_app1.scss`, `_app2.scss`, etc. then `base.scss` will include:

```
@import 'app1';
@import 'app2';
...
```

This combines the partial files into one when you compile. (You don't have to separate them, but it might be cleaner to do so.) Then, you do something like `<body class="app1">...` to use the `app1` namespace, and only rules from `_app1.scss` will apply.